# Why does this program compiles ? Should it not give an error as I am deleting the same thing twice

Tags: c++, oop, heap-memory

This code runs perfectly fine and does not give any error which I think it should as I am deleting the same thing twice.

```
#include<iostream>
int main(){
        int* var1 = new int;
        int* var2 = var1;
        *var1 = 10;
        *var2 = 15;
        std::cout << var1 << std::endl;
        std::cout<<var2<<std::endl;
        delete var1;
        delete var2;
        std::cout<<"Hello World";
return 0;}
```

Comment: Are you asking about compiling it without errors or running it without errors?

Comment: "I am deleting the same thing twice" Where do you think you are doing that? I do not see it.

Comment: The code you show doesn't "delete" anything. It have a memory leak though, since you have no `delete` matchning your `new`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I challenge your dupe. Nobody asked about undefined behaviour here. UB is not even obvious here. Please elaborate and be more careful with your hammer.

Comment: Deleting something twice is a runtime problem, not a compile-time error, and you aren't deleting anything here even once.

Comment: @Yunnosch yeah i edited the code , didnt paste it correctly first time

Comment: @UmarSaeedCheema *This code runs perfectly fine and does not give any error* -- The code is not running "fine".  C++ has something called *undefined behavior*.  Accessing an already deallocated memory is undefined behavior..

Comment: The behavior of the program is, as you suspected, undefined, Undefined behavior means only that the language definition does not tell you what the program does. It does not mean that something bad will happen. Sometimes the program seems to do just what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 0):

The variables `var1` and `var2` are stack variables, but the addresses they hold are not. The address that a pointer holds might point to garbage, to the stack, to the heap or to the data segment. Neither would be automatically deleted when the pointer is dead.

In your first post of the code it seemed that you assume a local pointer variable is dead, by getting out of scope and frees the address that it holds. This is not the case. This is why heap allocation requires manual freeing.

But then you posted the edit with two calls to `delete`.

In your program, `var1` and `var2` point to the same place on the heap, which is perfectly fine.

Then their content is populated with different values, which is also ok. Each assignment overrides the previous as it is written to the same place in memory.

As for the two calls to `delete` on the same address, the compiler doesn't follow what your code does. It only compiles the code and checks for specific errors that the specification required it to check.

The compiler in most cases cannot actually notice if an address is deleted twice, so it would probably not even try to give a warning, even if you delete the exact same variable twice, consequently. For example, [both gcc and clang](https://godbolt.org/z/93csoc) doesn't raise any warning for the following code, which is fine, they are not supposed to:

```
int main() {
    int* ptr = new int;
    delete ptr;
    delete ptr;
}
```

Static analysis tools may analyze this and point at the problematic code, but it is not the job of the compiler.

Comment: @Yunnosch Well it is a moving target as the answer was _being written_ before the edit... Only noticed the edit after posting it. Never mind, I'll edit the answer in the hope that the code in question won't change again...

Comment: A moving target question can be blamed on the author (so much so that in some cases I roll them back). An edit to the question which becomes visible before any answer cannot be blamed on the author. You on the other hand can be expected to notice an edit to the question which occurred before your answer became visible.